# Search referenced types in Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I'm trying to search for referenced types in Monodevelop.

I'm fairly new to Mono (and .NET development in general). In Eclipse I'd open a window and I could search for any given type/class in any of the project's referenced libraries.

Is it possible to do such a thing in Monodevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search types in referenced assemblies in MD 3.0, open the assembly browser and use the search panel there. To navigate to types in your own projects, use the [Navigate To](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/02/monodevelop_tips_navigate_files_and_types) command.

Comment: yeah, I've gotten used to alt+shift+o and ctrl+,. Does Monodevelop 2.8.6 have anything similar to browse assemblies?

Comment: Nope. Probably the closest thing is [Import Type](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/02/08/monodevelop_tips_import_type) completion.

Comment: Whoa! That is an awesome feature! Thanks :)